# Bind list of lists in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I have a List of `Authors`. Each of these `Authors` has a List of `Books`. From this list of `Authors`, I would like to display *all* of the books for every author as a databinding. I want to achieve this purely through XAML as I don't believe that I should have to resort to code-behind for a purely UI issue (the data is already available after-all..).

The closest I have got is below using nested ListViews, cycling first through my list of Authors (which belong to an object; SelectedBookshop), and then cycling through all of the books:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedBookshop.Authors}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Book Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This will display all of the books, but will display a separate ListView for each author!

To further complicate the problem, it would be nice to access fields from the `Author` object in this inner ListView, which I cannot find a solution for using this method.

The code-behind solution would be something along the lines of:

```
MyListView.ItemsSource = ((SelectedBookshop
                             .SelectMany(b => b.Authors))
                             .SelectMany(a => a.Books)).ToList()
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Either use a TreeView, or two ListViews, where the second one shows all books of the Author that is *selected* in the first one.

Comment: Have you tried using an ItemTemplate on the inner ListView (instead of the View)? Maybe go for a card style layout instead (e.g. name, image, etc)?

Comment: You could also use grouping in a DataGrid, ListView, or ListBox.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! So I've just looked into TreeViews and my use of a nested ListView seems to be a crude implementation of this. But my desire is to *flatten* the list, like using `SelectMany` in a LINQ statement would achieve. I don't want any reference of Authors, just all of their books in a list.

Comment: @Clemens to clarify, there is no *selected* Author, it's a list of all the books for every Author.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I could be wrong, but isn't grouping for achieving this unwanted behaviour of listing the authors separately? i.e., grouping by the authors.

Comment: @Laurence Grouping would be a list of authors with each author’s books listed under his name. What you’ve got, but all in one control. But if you want a flat list with an Author column and a Book column, having the viewmodel expose the result of a SelectMany query seems like a perfect solution.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, but I don't want any reference to the Author. That feature is present in this nested ListView, and I don't want it to be there. I just want a flat list of every book relevant to that bookshop.

Comment: @Laurence I’d do the SelectMany.

Comment: Don't make things more complicated than necessary. Create a view model with the combined list of all books of all authors, e.g. by SelectMany. Or if the lists aren't ObservableCollections, write a Binding Converter that converts a collection of authors to a collection of all their books.

Comment: @Clemens That sounds like the cleanest way. I'm just surprised there isn't a way to achieve this in XAML - I would have thought creating an entire viewmodel for a single ListView would have been overcomplicating it. Anyway, I'll do this - thank you for your help!

Comment: @Laurence Creating an entire viewmodel for a single ListView does seem like overkill; who suggested it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Did I misunderstand Clemens comment above?

Comment: @Laurence Ohh, “create a viewmodel with...”. I think he expressed himself imperfectly; the SelectMany property would best just be a fairly trivial addition to your existing viewmodel. Not that creating a new viewmodel is a big deal: inherit from your viewmodel base class and add a property or two. Done.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah, when updating the selectedBookshop property the triggered Load function could also populate some "AllBookshopBooks" property. You're right, this could easily be accommodated in either ViewModel, but I went for creating a new one as I envisage there being some more details I would like to pull out later on. Thanks again!